# C# how to inherit generic method with differing number of required parameters

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, parameters, polymorphism

When inheriting a method with a generic parameter in C#, what's the best way to handle cases where no parameter is actually required in the child class? For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
public abstract class Parent { 
    protected abstract void Load<T>(T param); 
}
public class Child : Parent {
    protected override void Load() {}
}
```

If something like this isn't possible, is there a suggested standard practice for specifying T in cases where it's not actually required? Do I just set to something like bool and ignore the value?

```
child.Load<bool>(false);
```

Comment: Some additional context would be helpful:  Is `T` a generic parameter of the `Parent` class or just that method?  Does `Child` inherit from `Parent`? Does `Child.Load` reuse any code from `Parent.Load<T>`?

Comment: If its not required... one wonders why its there in the first place; or why you are deriving from it.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that the two methods are semantically different and shouldn't be overriding each other or there's a misuse of generics somewhere. Can you elaborate on the use case?

Comment: The real world case involved trying to create a generic loader method for UI elements which may or may not need contextual data passed in. I was trying to figure out a way to make this work with polymorphism, but thinking it over, this isn't actually necessary in my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When overriding a function you have to keep the same number (and types) of parameters.  You can *overload* the parent method but not *override* it:

```
public abstract class Parent { 
    protected abstract void Load<T>(T param); 
}
public class Child : Parent {
    protected void Load() {}
    protected override void Load<T>(T param) { // do nothing? }
}
```

However this is a code smell to me - making `Load<T>` abstract essentially tells implementers that they *must* implement this method, but this class feels it does not need to do so.  If code within `Parent` expects `Load<T>` to be properly overridden; how will it know that `Child` implements some other flavor of `Load`?

Comment: Minor nits: virtual members can't be `private`, and you're not allowed to change accessibility anyway (e.g. from `public` to `protected` or vice a versa). Also, in the above example `Child` doesn't actually inherit `Parent`. I mean, I think the idea of the code is clear enough, but it'd be better if it were legal.